# How to search specific fields and return entire fields in elasticsearch using c#

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have a following model class which is used to indexing documents in elasticsearch.

```
public class SearchModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string SubCategory { get; set; }
    public List<SearchItem> SearchItems = new List<SearchItem>();

}

public class SearchItem
{
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public string ItemValue { get; set; }
}
```

I want to search in Category, SubCategory, and ItemValue and return all the SearchModel class. My current search method is

```
var response = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<SearchModel>(
            s =>
            //s.Query(q => q
            //    .Match(m => m
            //        .Field(f => f.Category)
            //        .Field(f => f.SubCategory)
            //        .Field(f => f.SearchItems)
            //        .Query(String.Format("*{0}*", query))
            //    )
            //));
            s.Query(q => q.QueryString(d => d.Query(String.Format("*{0}*", query))))
                .From((page - 1) * pageSize)
                .Size(pageSize));
```

An example search result is

```
{
"aggregations": {},
"aggs": {},
"documents": [
    {
        "searchItems": [
            {
                "itemName": "SerialNumber",
                "itemValue": "DP5996"
            },
            {
                "itemName": "SkuNumber",
                "itemValue": "SKU5996"
            },
            {
                "itemName": "WorkOrderNumber",
                "itemValue": "WO-DP5996"
            },
            {
                "itemName": "ComponentId",
                "itemValue": "5c5d5830468ccf615cf80244"
            },
            {
                "itemName": "ComponentName",
                "itemValue": "Pressure Gauge"
            },
            {
                "itemName": "bandColor",
                "itemValue": "YELLOW"
            },
            {
                "itemName": "pressure",
                "itemValue": "15599"
            },
            {
                "itemName": "pressureUOM",
                "itemValue": "PSI"
            },
            {
                "itemName": "size",
                "itemValue": "2 3/8"
            },
            {
                "itemName": "sizeUOM",
                "itemValue": "FT_IN"
            },
            {
                "itemName": "boxInnerDia",
                "itemValue": "16"
            },
            {
                "itemName": "boxInnerDiaUOM",
                "itemValue": "IN"
            },
            {
                "itemName": "boxOuterDia",
                "itemValue": "18"
            },
            {
                "itemName": "boxOuterDiaUOM",
                "itemValue": "IN"
            },
            {
                "itemName": "classColor",
                "itemValue": "RED"
            },
            {
                "itemName": "grade",
                "itemValue": "E-75 EU"
            },
            {
                "itemName": "hardBanding",
                "itemValue": ""
            },
            {
                "itemName": "hbVendor",
                "itemValue": ""
            },
            {
                "itemName": "ipc",
                "itemValue": ""
            },
            {
                "itemName": "makeUpLength",
                "itemValue": "0"
            },
            {
                "itemName": "makeUpLengthUOM",
                "itemValue": ""
            },
            {
                "itemName": "manufacturer",
                "itemValue": "American Oil drilling Inc."
            },
            {
                "itemName": "pipeInnerDia",
                "itemValue": "0"
            },
            {
                "itemName": "pipeInnerDiaUOM",
                "itemValue": "IN"
            },
            {
                "itemName": "pipeOuterDia",
                "itemValue": "0"
            },
            {
                "itemName": "pipeOuterDiaUOM",
                "itemValue": "IN"
            },
            {
                "itemName": "pipeLength",
                "itemValue": "5"
            },
            {
                "itemName": "tubularType",
                "itemValue": ""
            },
            {
                "itemName": "weight",
                "itemValue": "50"
            },
            {
                "itemName": "weightUOM",
                "itemValue": "KG"
            }
        ],
        "id": "5c65772d01577532bccfeba6",
        "category": "Asset",
        "categoryId": "5c65772d01577532bccfeba6",
        "subCategory": "gauge"
    }
],
"fields": [
    null
],
"hits": [
    {
        "explanation": null,
        "fields": null,
        "highlights": {},
        "id": "5c65772d01577532bccfeba6",
        "index": "blackgold",
        "innerHits": {},
        "matchedQueries": [],
        "nested": null,
        "parent": null,
        "routing": null,
        "score": 1,
        "sorts": [],
        "source": {
            "searchItems": [
                {
                    "itemName": "SerialNumber",
                    "itemValue": "DP5996"
                },
                {
                    "itemName": "SkuNumber",
                    "itemValue": "SKU5996"
                },
                {
                    "itemName": "WorkOrderNumber",
                    "itemValue": "WO-DP5996"
                },
                {
                    "itemName": "ComponentId",
                    "itemValue": "5c5d5830468ccf615cf80244"
                },
                {
                    "itemName": "ComponentName",
                    "itemValue": "Pressure Gauge"
                },
                {
                    "itemName": "bandColor",
                    "itemValue": "YELLOW"
                },
                {
                    "itemName": "pressure",
                    "itemValue": "15599"
                },
                {
                    "itemName": "pressureUOM",
                    "itemValue": "PSI"
                },
                {
                    "itemName": "size",
                    "itemValue": "2 3/8"
                },
                {
                    "itemName": "sizeUOM",
                    "itemValue": "FT_IN"
                },
                {
                    "itemName": "boxInnerDia",
                    "itemValue": "16"
                },
                {
                    "itemName": "boxInnerDiaUOM",
                    "itemValue": "IN"
                },
                {
                    "itemName": "boxOuterDia",
                    "itemValue": "18"
                },
                {
                    "itemName": "boxOuterDiaUOM",
                    "itemValue": "IN"
                },
                {
                    "itemName": "classColor",
                    "itemValue": "RED"
                },
                {
                    "itemName": "grade",
                    "itemValue": "E-75 EU"
                },
                {
                    "itemName": "hardBanding",
                    "itemValue": ""
                },
                {
                    "itemName": "hbVendor",
                    "itemValue": ""
                },
                {
                    "itemName": "ipc",
                    "itemValue": ""
                },
                {
                    "itemName": "makeUpLength",
                    "itemValue": "0"
                },
                {
                    "itemName": "makeUpLengthUOM",
                    "itemValue": ""
                },
                {
                    "itemName": "manufacturer",
                    "itemValue": "American Oil drilling Inc."
                },
                {
                    "itemName": "pipeInnerDia",
                    "itemValue": "0"
                },
                {
                    "itemName": "pipeInnerDiaUOM",
                    "itemValue": "IN"
                },
                {
                    "itemName": "pipeOuterDia",
                    "itemValue": "0"
                },
                {
                    "itemName": "pipeOuterDiaUOM",
                    "itemValue": "IN"
                },
                {
                    "itemName": "pipeLength",
                    "itemValue": "5"
                },
                {
                    "itemName": "tubularType",
                    "itemValue": ""
                },
                {
                    "itemName": "weight",
                    "itemValue": "50"
                },
                {
                    "itemName": "weightUOM",
                    "itemValue": "KG"
                }
            ],
            "id": "5c65772d01577532bccfeba6",
            "category": "Asset",
            "categoryId": "5c65772d01577532bccfeba6",
            "subCategory": "gauge"
        },
        "type": "searchmodel",
        "version": null
    }
],
"hitsMetadata": {
    "hits": [
        {
            "explanation": null,
            "fields": null,
            "highlights": {},
            "id": "5c65772d01577532bccfeba6",
            "index": "blackgold",
            "innerHits": {},
            "matchedQueries": [],
            "nested": null,
            "parent": null,
            "routing": null,
            "score": 1,
            "sorts": [],
            "source": {
                "searchItems": [
                    {
                        "itemName": "SerialNumber",
                        "itemValue": "DP5996"
                    },
                    {
                        "itemName": "SkuNumber",
                        "itemValue": "SKU5996"
                    },
                    {
                        "itemName": "WorkOrderNumber",
                        "itemValue": "WO-DP5996"
                    },
                    {
                        "itemName": "ComponentId",
                        "itemValue": "5c5d5830468ccf615cf80244"
                    },
                    {
                        "itemName": "ComponentName",
                        "itemValue": "Pressure Gauge"
                    },
                    {
                        "itemName": "bandColor",
                        "itemValue": "YELLOW"
                    },
                    {
                        "itemName": "pressure",
                        "itemValue": "15599"
                    },
                    {
                        "itemName": "pressureUOM",
                        "itemValue": "PSI"
                    },
                    {
                        "itemName": "size",
                        "itemValue": "2 3/8"
                    },
                    {
                        "itemName": "sizeUOM",
                        "itemValue": "FT_IN"
                    },
                    {
                        "itemName": "boxInnerDia",
                        "itemValue": "16"
                    },
                    {
                        "itemName": "boxInnerDiaUOM",
                        "itemValue": "IN"
                    },
                    {
                        "itemName": "boxOuterDia",
                        "itemValue": "18"
                    },
                    {
                        "itemName": "boxOuterDiaUOM",
                        "itemValue": "IN"
                    },
                    {
                        "itemName": "classColor",
                        "itemValue": "RED"
                    },
                    {
                        "itemName": "grade",
                        "itemValue": "E-75 EU"
                    },
                    {
                        "itemName": "hardBanding",
                        "itemValue": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "itemName": "hbVendor",
                        "itemValue": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "itemName": "ipc",
                        "itemValue": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "itemName": "makeUpLength",
                        "itemValue": "0"
                    },
                    {
                        "itemName": "makeUpLengthUOM",
                        "itemValue": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "itemName": "manufacturer",
                        "itemValue": "American Oil drilling Inc."
                    },
                    {
                        "itemName": "pipeInnerDia",
                        "itemValue": "0"
                    },
                    {
                        "itemName": "pipeInnerDiaUOM",
                        "itemValue": "IN"
                    },
                    {
                        "itemName": "pipeOuterDia",
                        "itemValue": "0"
                    },
                    {
                        "itemName": "pipeOuterDiaUOM",
                        "itemValue": "IN"
                    },
                    {
                        "itemName": "pipeLength",
                        "itemValue": "5"
                    },
                    {
                        "itemName": "tubularType",
                        "itemValue": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "itemName": "weight",
                        "itemValue": "50"
                    },
                    {
                        "itemName": "weightUOM",
                        "itemValue": "KG"
                    }
                ],
                "id": "5c65772d01577532bccfeba6",
                "category": "Asset",
                "categoryId": "5c65772d01577532bccfeba6",
                "subCategory": "gauge"
            },
            "type": "searchmodel",
            "version": null
        }
    ],
    "maxScore": 1,
    "total": 1
},
"maxScore": 1,
"numberOfReducePhases": 0,
"profile": null,
"scrollId": null,
"shards": {
    "failed": 0,
    "failures": [],
    "successful": 5,
    "total": 5
},
"suggest": {},
"terminatedEarly": false,
"timedOut": false,
"took": 20,
"total": 1,
"apiCall": {
    "auditTrail": [
        {
            "ended": "2019-02-20T09:46:31.4591331Z",
            "event": 10,
            "exception": null,
            "node": {
                "clientNode": false,
                "deadUntil": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
                "failedAttempts": 0,
                "holdsData": true,
                "httpEnabled": true,
                "id": null,
                "ingestEnabled": false,
                "isAlive": true,
                "isResurrected": false,
                "masterEligible": true,
                "masterOnlyNode": false,
                "name": null,
                "settings": {},
                "uri": "http://localhost:9200/"
            },
            "path": "blackgold/searchmodel/_search?typed_keys=true",
            "started": "2019-02-20T09:46:31.1551544Z"
        }
    ],
    "debugInformation": "Successful low level call on POST: /blackgold/searchmodel/_search?typed_keys=true\r\n# Audit trail of this API call:\r\n - [1] HealthyResponse: Node: http://localhost:9200/ Took: 00:00:00.3039787\r\n# Request:\r\n<Request stream not captured or already read to completion by serializer. Set DisableDirectStreaming() on ConnectionSettings to force it to be set on the response.>\r\n# Response:\r\n<Response stream not captured or already read to completion by serializer. Set DisableDirectStreaming() on ConnectionSettings to force it to be set on the response.>\r\n",
    "deprecationWarnings": [],
    "httpMethod": 1,
    "httpStatusCode": 200,
    "originalException": null,
    "requestBodyInBytes": null,
    "responseBodyInBytes": null,
    "responseMimeType": "application/json",
    "serverError": null,
    "success": true,
    "successOrKnownError": true,
    "uri": "http://localhost:9200/blackgold/searchmodel/_search?typed_keys=true"
},
"debugInformation": "Valid NEST response built from a successful low level call on POST: /blackgold/searchmodel/_search?typed_keys=true\r\n# Audit trail of this API call:\r\n - [1] HealthyResponse: Node: http://localhost:9200/ Took: 00:00:00.3039787\r\n# Request:\r\n<Request stream not captured or already read to completion by serializer. Set DisableDirectStreaming() on ConnectionSettings to force it to be set on the response.>\r\n# Response:\r\n<Response stream not captured or already read to completion by serializer. Set DisableDirectStreaming() on ConnectionSettings to force it to be set on the response.>\r\n",
"isValid": true,
"originalException": null,
"serverError": null
}
```

**Updated**

In c# indexing is done by following code, also need to avoid those Id fields which contains values like '5c65772d07894532bccfeba'

```
        var searchModel = new SearchModel();
    var searchItems = new List<SearchItem>();
    searchModel.Id = "5c65772d07894532bccfeba";
    searchModel.Category = "Asset";
    searchModel.CategoryId = "5c65772d07894532bccfeba";
    searchModel.SubCategory = "test category";
    var item1 = new SearchItem
    {
        ItemName = "SerialNumber",
        ItemValue = "DP123"
    };
    searchItems.Add(item1);
    var item2 = new SearchItem
    {
        ItemName = "SkuNumber",
        ItemValue = "test"
    };
    searchItems.Add(item2);
    var item3 = new SearchItem
    {
        ItemName = "WorkOrderNumber",
        ItemValue = "TestOrder123"
    };
    searchItems.Add(item3);
    var item4 = new SearchItem
    {
        ItemName = "ComponentId",
        ItemValue = "5c65772d01577532bccfeba"
    };
    searchItems.Add(item4);
    var item5 = new SearchItem
    {
        ItemName = "ComponentName",
        ItemValue = "TestComponent"
    };
    searchItems.Add(item5);
    searchModel.SearchItems = searchItems;
    var response = await _elasticClient.IndexDocumentAsync(searchModel);
```

This result getting when I used query string as 'dp' which contains in SerialNumber. I want to avoid searching 'dp' in id fields.
I tried the commented code but not returning any data. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please join mappings + example.

Comment: I added an example search result.

Comment: Ok so you try to make a querry you search for words in Category OR SubCategory OR SearchItems right? Can you post also example of your querry variable, and also, your index mappings.

Comment: I added example indexing

Comment: Note: `.Match()` does not allow multiple fields to be specified, so calling multiple times as in your commented example means that only the last `.Field(...)` call will set the field. Where multiple fields should be specified, use `.MultiMatch()`, or combine multiple queries with `.Bool()`